# Hide a list in sharepoint but update it with javascript api

Tags: list, sharepoint

Ι am aware of the fact that I can use permission levels to hide a certain list from others. At the same time, I would like to use the javascript api to write to the same list. That it, I would like to use the list as an internal data keeping list not visible to all but accessible to everyone (through the api). 
Is this possible? I am asking because if you set permission levels on who gets to see the list, don't they (the permissions) affect what you can do with the api? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the JavaScript APIs are limited in what they can do based on the permission of the user running the script.

You can use the JSOM API to make a hidden list, which will not be visible on the site contents page, but to which end users can still have access. This is similar to how the SharePoint 2010 Workflow History List is hidden. Use the JSOM API to set a list's [Hidden](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee547407(v=office.14).aspx) property to be true, or when you create the list, set its [custom schema XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee554010(v=office.14).aspx) so that the `Hidden` attribute of the List element is set to true; see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.schemaxml.aspx) for a list schema XML reference.